# Dialogflow audio playlist? Next Previous

Tags: javascript, audio, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

After searching for hours/days if there's a way to create a audio playlist with Dialogflow it seem that this function do not exist. (Like Spotify, Google Play audio playlist)

When i play a audio file from my Google assistant skill on my Google nest hub. There's a automatic non functionning Next & Previous button.

I created a player intent (Like the Radio player demo) with training phrase like, Next, Previous, Rewind, foward ect..

I indexed my json audio list. If i say Next. Google assistant will take over and will foward the video to end. Default message (I hope you enjoyed the tune).

Only play, pause work,

To test my code, i replace to word Next with Test in training phrase to play the next audio files and it't working. (In my javascript index.js file, the TEST word call a function to play the next audio from a json file). but if i say NEXT Google assistant take over and end the audio since there's no playlist setting. If i say Previous it will restart the audio file.

1 - Can we overwrite or disable Google assistant default player control behavior?

2 - Is there a way, methode to really create a playlist that Google assistant will understand?

I use the Dialogflow board javascript fulfillment (index.js)

Comment: To be clear - is this an Action using the Media Response? Or is this something else?

Comment: yes, the Media Respond